# VBA 2 IF conditions applied for column

Tags: vba, excel

this is my first post, please be patient if I'm doing/asking something wrong.
My issue is:
I got 2 columns, A is number of children, B is name of those children.
Those values are manually entered, I simply would like to have B mandatory if A is filled.
Here is what I thought:

```
    Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
        If Not IsEmpty(Sheet1.Range("A1")) Then
            If IsEmpty(Sheet1.Range("B1")) Then
                MsgBox "Please fill in cell B1 before closing."
                Cancel = True
            Else '
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

This is actually working perfectly, unfortunately I can't manage to extend it for whole columns, when replacing A1 with A1:A1000 and B1 with B1:B1000 for instance,it doesn't work.

How can I validate this for both entire column A and B?

thanks in advance!

Comment: What you need is a loop going through the column.

Comment: If VBA/Excel can't give you the intelligence to check if for each filled in cell of column A, the cell of column B is also filled in, then you have to write a loop that goes through the A column and checks the B column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Cancel = Evaluate("SUMPRODUCT(--(ISBLANK(Sheet1!B:B) <> ISBLANK(Sheet1!A:A)))")
    If Cancel Then MsgBox "Please fill in column B before closing."
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

In order to take the user to the place where data is missing, and taking into account the additional information you provided about your data, try this:

```
'Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
 Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim r: r = Evaluate( _
      "MATCH(FALSE, ISBLANK('ELENCO AGGIORNATO'!V:V) = ISBLANK('ELENCO AGGIORNATO'!W:W), 0)")
    If IsError(r) Then Exit Sub ' All is fine
    Cancel = True
    Application.Goto Sheets("ELENCO AGGIORNATO").Cells(r, "V").Resize(, 2)
    msgBox "Please fill missing data before saving."
End Sub
```

Also note that I recommend `Workbook_BeforeSave` instead of `Workbook_BeforeClose`, because there's no harm if the user decides to drop his (incomplete) work and close the workbook without saving.

Comment: Thanks!This works perfectly on a fresh excel file.The one I am trying to apply this code to is has already 8000 rows filled.On this file, columns are V (number of children) and W(name of children).However, when I paste this code into my complete file, I fill a cell in column V, leave blank the next one on the same row in column W, and I can save the file..it doesn't stop me, despite I have updated ISBLANK(Sheet1!B:B) with ISBLANK(Sheet1!W:W) , and the other one with V:V.My sheet is named ELENCO AGGIORNATO, but it is marked as Sheet1 between the Microsoft Excel Objects in VBE, please help!

Comment: @DiegoTrec just replace `Sheet1` with the name of your workheet enclosed by single quotes. Your other modifications are fine. `'ELENCO AGGIORNATO'!V:V` and `'ELENCO AGGIORNATO'!W:W`

Comment: thanks again, it works.Sorry about that, but now it won't let me close the file, even If I have filtered the V column to see if any cell in V was empty while the correspondednt in W filled, and see no errors, it keeps saying that I have to fill the column before closing..It must be an error somewhere or it could be something else?

Comment: That shouldn't be the case. Are you sure that column V is completely filled in the range you are using in the code and corresponding cell in column W are also filled? In any of those column values derived from a formula?

Comment: @DiegoTrec note that my formula checks if both columns `V` and `W` match together, none should be filled at a place when the other is empty. Besides, empty cells should be really empty, not filled with some blank characters.

Comment: @sktneer nope, Column V is not completely filled, it is filled on both V and W only when a record has children and the name is typed, does it have to be completely filled?

Comment: @DiegoTrec dont worry for the large number of rows, the chosen method is extremely fast. I added a new version which takes the user to the first guilty row. Plz try it and also take a look at the comments.

Comment: @A.S.H thank you again for helping me, I feel it is something really silly, but it still stops at Application.Goto Sheets("ELENCO AGGIORNATO").Cells(r, "V").Resize(, 2) with '32809' error, tried to change the name of the sheet without spaces naming just "ELENCO", but it stops there again..

Comment: @A.S.H not sure what was the problem, I rebuilt the file and it is working smoothly, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this...

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim str As String
    Dim Rng As Range, Cell As Range
    Dim FoundBlank As Boolean
    Set Rng = Sheet1.Range("A1:A1000")
    str = "Please fill the cells listed below before colsing..." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
    For Each Cell In Rng
        If Cell <> "" And Cell.Offset(0, 1) = "" Then
            FoundBlank = True
            str = str & Cell.Address(0, 1) & vbNewLine
        End If
    Next Cell
    If FoundBlank Then
        Cancel = True
        MsgBox str, vbExclamation, "List of Blank Cells Found!"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Just a minor change. As OP wants `Column B` to be mandatory, `str = str & Cell.Address(0, 0) & vbNewLine`should be `str = str & Cell.Offset(0, 1).Address(0, 0) & vbNewLine`.

Comment: Good catch Mrig! Thanks for pointing that out. Much appreciated. :)

Comment: Brillant, thanks sktneer and Mrig.This works perfectly on a fresh excel file.The one I am trying to apply this code to is has already 8000 rows filled.On this file, columns are V (number of children) and W(name of children).However, when I paste this code into my complete file, it crashes here Set Rng = Sheet1.Range("A1:A1000") , despite I have updated A1:A1000 with V1:V10000, and renamed Sheet1.Range with ELENCO AGGIORNATO.Range (ELENCO AGGIORNATO is the name of the sheet), please help, I don't have any clue!!

Comment: Sheet1 in that line is the CodeName of the sheet. Make sure that Sheet with Sheet1 CodeName exists in the workbook. Otherwise you can write it like Set Rng = Sheets("YourSheetNameHere").Range("V1:V10000")

Comment: thanks, tried with both Set Rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("V1:V10000") or Set Rng = Sheets("ELENCO AGGIORNATO").Range("V1:V10000"), but it now shows Run- time error '9', Subscript out of range,the sheet is marked as Sheet1 and the name is ELENCO AGGIORNATO

Comment: Subscript out of range error simple means that the sheet you are referencing in the code doesn't exist in the workbook. You can find the codename of the sheet in the project explorer on VB Editor. Locate the correct sheet and use the code name of that sheet or correct sheet name in the code. Would be better if you declare a worksheet variable say Dim ws as worksheet and set the ws before setting the range. And later you can set the range like set rng=ws.range("v1:v10000"). So if there is an issue with the worksheet code will fail on set ws line.